# How can I get state/province codes for the postal codes in python?

Tags: python, zipcode, postal-code

I have a list of US postal codes. I want to obtain their Province code in python. 
For example : '66002'  should give 'KS', '94611' should get 'CA' and likewise.

Is there a function available in python that can facilitate this query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the package uszipcode (https://pypi.org/project/uszipcode/), in the documentation is explained how to access to the different information of each zipcode.